# In react useReducer store loses state when I route to another page. useContext loads only initial state

Tags: reactjs, use-context, use-reducer

State is saved well on page and gets changed and interactive, but once I navigate to another page - state is reset

The whole store and createContext is

```
type Action2 =
   {
      type: "ON";
      payload: boolean;
    }
  | {
      type: "OFF";
      payload: boolean;
}


type State2 = {
  isLoggedIn: boolean
};

const reducer2 = (state: State2, action: Action2): State2 => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ON":
      return {
        isLoggedIn:true
      };
    case "OFF":
      return {
        isLoggedIn:false
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};


const initialState: State2 = {
  isLoggedIn: false
};
```

initializing state

```
const [state2, dispatch2] = React.useReducer(reducer2, {"isLoggedIn":false});
```

buttons for changing state

```
<Button onClick={()=>dispatch2({type:"ON",payload:true})}>
            ON
          </Button>
           <Button onClick={()=>dispatch2({type:"OFF",payload:true})}>
            OFF
          </Button>
```

Providing context to an element rendered in routes

```
<Route exact path="/:id" >
<MyContext.Provider value={[state2, dispatch2]}>
            <React.Fragment>
                <PatientPage settingpatient={fetchPatient} context={context}/>
            </React.Fragment>
            </MyContext.Provider>
</Route>
```

in the element I access state from context

```
const theme2 = React.useContext(MyContext);
```

and is it always {isLoggedIn:false}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is fine, react loses the state when you navigate to another page (i assume you do it from your browser) because it causes a page reload, this is why you use `history` or `Link` component to properly navigate using `react-router`

Usually you save the `state` in `localHistory` or use cookies to solve the "user is logged in" issue

Comment: thank you for great advices! Button As={Link}  or just Link work. Now I could share state between components! Many hours wasted

Comment: How to use history? I do not understand

Comment: you can use `Link` as a component, it redirects to `to` when the user clicks its child, or you can use `history` to programmatically redirect the user into some path `history.push(path)`

you can use `history` by simply importing its hook like this

`const history = useHistory()` then use `history.push(path)` wherever you want..

Comment: @JustABeginner this also would be interesting to me